# $ sign in javascript is trying to kill me, who can get me out of it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to nodejs, I known $ is used in jQuery, but the tutorial I'm learning shows me the following piece of code, which confused me by it's '$',

```
var $ = cheerio.load(res.text);
    $('#topic_list .topic_title').each(function (idx, element) {
      var $element = $(element);
      var href = url.resolve(cnodeUrl, $element.attr('href'));
      topicUrls.push(href);
    });
```

can anyone try to explain the 5 $s here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _[Cheerio implements a subset of core jQuery...](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)_

Comment: You can return function from something and then call it. Would calling that `doc_fn` make more sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way that you can have a variable named a, you can have a variable named $ or _. searching google on variable names in javascript will provide more info, but to the point of your question, consider this:

```
var a = 1; //creates a variable named a, value is one
var $ = 1; //creates a variable named $, value is one
```

because it is javascript, a variable can also hold a function:

```
var a = function(){return 1;}  // calling a() will return one
var $ = function(){return 1;}  // $ is a var whose value is a function.
```

Now, when you have a function that you call very frequently, forexample JQuery library has a function called JQuery() which wraps elements and contains everything else, it makes sense to have a shortcut for it:

```
function JQuery(){...} //everything that JQuery does
var $ = JQuery;  //now $() is the shorthand for JQuery()
```

Again, because it is Javascript, a function can return a value, or another function:

```
var cheerio = { 
   load: function(start){ 
            return function(end){ return start + " " + end }
   }
}

var $ = cheerio.load("hello");
$("world"); // will return "hello world"
$("my friend"); //will return "hello my friend"
```

In your sample code, $ has been used as a shorthand for ther return value of cheerio.load() function. so, `$('#topic_list .topic_title')` is equivalent to

```
cheerio.load(res.text)('#topic_list .topic_title')
```

meaning that `cheerio.load(res.text)` is expected to return a function that can later be called. so from the second line of your sample code, $ is nothing but that function. if you had JQuery before that, you can still use JQuery() instead of $().

$element is just a variable name, a visual clue that it is the result of $(element). you could have as easily said `var froggy=$(element)` but $element is more readable.

Comment: Thank you Reza, I feel better now :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to confused with $. Here $ is just variable and nothing you may assign anything else if you want. We are using $ because [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) is similar to jquery and easy to understand who know about jquery. You can write like

```
var cheerText = cheerio.load(res.text);
cheerText('#topic_list .topic_title').each(function (idx, element) {
  var element = cheerText(element);
  var href = url.resolve(cnodeUrl, element.attr('href'));
  topicUrls.push(href);
});
```